# Преобразование картинки base64 в PNG

Tags: base64, canvas, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, нужно сохранить рисунок с canvas, добавил кнопку и повесил событие:

```
save.onclick = function (event) {
    var tmp = canvas.toDataURL();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: "img="+tmp,
        success: function(msg)
        {
            var text = document.getElementById("result");
            text.innerHTML=msg;
        }
    });
}
```

На сервер приходит следующее:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA .. и так далее

нужно как-то преобразовать в png, делал так:

```
$img= base64_decode($_POST['img']);
$fpng = fopen("img.png", "w");
fwrite($fpng,$img);
fclose($fpng);
```

Изображение создаётся, но оно не открывается, весит около 191 кб
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли удалить "data:image/png;base64" и заменить символы пробела на "+".

```
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$result = file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($img));
```